# A problems occured evaluation project: ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I'm trying to start the app it opens the "Edit Configuration" window instead of starting it up, and it shows an error at the buttom: "Gradle Project Sync Failed. Please fix your project and try again"

So I am trying to **Clean / Rebuild Project**, and I keep getting this error:

> Error:(5, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> Invalid revision: 24.0.two

When clicking on it, it opens my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.two"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example5.user.tapper"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "one.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:two.two.two', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.two.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.two.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:one.0.0-alpha8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fluffyBatman, I found a solution:

I uploaded 3 images to @drawables called "1.png" , "2.png" and "3.png" and renamed them to "one.png", "two.png", etc. Now, I might have accidentally pressed on something that changed the entire "1"/"2"/"3" in my project to "one", "two", "three",

So: I simply renamed all of the "one","two","three" in my build.gradle to "1", "2" and "3", and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `buildToolsVersion "24.0.two"` to `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"` and sync again.

Comment: Thank you, thanks to that I found the full solution, see my answer :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Up vote my answer if that was helpful. :)

Comment: I did, but since I have less than 15 rep, it does not show, but it counts so dont worry :)